# How to get all Xpath of an xpath wildcard in oracle XMLTYPE

Tags: plsql, xquery, xmltype

I want to get xpath of  an node in oracle xmltype:

```
XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PO pono="1">
   <PNAME>Po_1</PNAME>
   <CUSTNAME>John</CUSTNAME>
   <AMT>1</AMT>
   <SHIPADDR>
      <STREET>1033, Main Street</STREET>
      <CITY>Sunnyvalue</CITY>
      <STATE>CA</STATE>
   </SHIPADDR>
</PO>')
```

A funtion FN_getpath('/PO/AMT' ) will return /PO[1]/AMT[1].

AND FN_getpath('/PO/SHIPADDR' ) will return:

```
/PO[1]/SHIPADDR[1]/CITY[1]/text()
/PO[1]/SHIPADDR[1]/STREET[1]
/PO[1]/SHIPADDR[1]/CITY[1]
/PO[1]/SHIPADDR[1]/STREET[1]/text()
/PO[1]/SHIPADDR[1]/STATE[1]
/PO[1]/SHIPADDR[1]
/PO[1]/SHIPADDR[1]/STATE[1]/text()
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Q: So want to write an Oracle function that will generate an XPath string from a template?

Comment: Yes, I want a function like that. I see an example in this link: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3962739/how-to-generate-xpath-string-from-xml-file. But it doesn't show all path.